# Getting Jquery code to stay after form has finished submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

My code Jquery code adds text to a table when a user makes a mistake in their form. However the text dissapears once it has finished checking and thus only appears for a brief split second.

Here is the Username validator:

```
function validateUserName()
{
    var u = document.forms["NewUser"]["user"].value
    var uLength = u.length;
    var illegalChars = /\W/; // allow letters, numbers, and underscores
    if (u == null || u == "")
    {
        $("#ErrorUser").text("You Left the Username field Emptyyy");
        return false;
    }
    else if (uLength <4 || uLength > 11)
    {
        $("#ErrorUser").text("The Username must be between 4 and 11 characters");
        return false;
    }
    else if (illegalChars.test(u)) 
    {
        $("#ErrorUser").text("The Username contains illegal charectors men!");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no code here that's making the text disappear.  Post the rest of your code.

Comment: You need to prevent the default submit of the form

Comment: Will this work, coz at the end of the first line there is no terminator `;`.

Comment: Good point, adeneo... the form should be `onsubmit="return validateUserName()"`  Not just `onsubmit="validateUserName()"`

Comment: @PraveenKumar: In JavaScript that's okay...

Comment: BTW, you don't need `else {return true;}`.  All other conditions return false, so just return true without the else.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the form submission, you need to prevent the default action. Give this way:

```
function validateUserName(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var u = document.forms["NewUser"]["user"].value;
    var uLength = u.length;
    var illegalChars = /\W/; // allow letters, numbers, and underscores
    if (u == null || u == "")
    {
        $("#ErrorUser").text("You Left the Username field Emptyyy");
        return false;
    }
    else if (uLength <4 || uLength > 11)
    {
        $("#ErrorUser").text("The Username must be between 4 and 11 characters");
        return false;
    }
    else if (illegalChars.test(u)) 
    {
        $("#ErrorUser").text("The Username contains illegal charectors men!");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And you need to call the event this way:

```
$("form").onsubmit(validateUserName);
```

---

**Update:** Based on the comment.

Change your `<form>` tag markup this way:

```
<form name="NewUser" id="myform">
```

And in the JavaScript, use this way:

```
$("form").onsubmit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var u = document.forms["NewUser"]["user"].value;
    var uLength = u.length;
    var illegalChars = /\W/; // allow letters, numbers, and underscores
    if (u == null || u == "")
    {
        $("#ErrorUser").text("You Left the Username field Emptyyy");
        return false;
    }
    else if (uLength <4 || uLength > 11)
    {
        $("#ErrorUser").text("The Username must be between 4 and 11 characters");
        return false;
    }
    else if (illegalChars.test(u)) 
    {
        $("#ErrorUser").text("The Username contains illegal charectors men!");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: There's no `e` passed in to that

Comment: This is my form submit line: <form name = "NewUser" onsubmit= "validateForm()"

What must I change it to?

Comment: I did that, but then nothing comes up when you press the submit button. Not even text for a few seconds like it was happening before?

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned in the comment by @adeneo, you need to prevent your form from submitting.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="if(!validateUserName()) return false;"/>
```

This will prevent your form from submitting data if the form has errors. You already return `true`/`false` from your Javascript function, just utilizing those.

Comment: This will never work.  You're just (incorrectly) copying other people's help

Comment: @StevenMoseley Care to enlighten WHY this won't work? Also, from where do you think I copied the code?

Comment: Before you edited it, it said `if(validateUserName())`.  Either way, you merely copied answers that were previously provided in comments.  You don't deserve the credit.

Comment: Furthermore, validation should always go on form submit, not on button click.  This question was correctly answered in the comments before you tried to copy it.

Comment: @StevenMoseley typos happen Steven :) You down voted before the edit, almost immediately after I posted and before I edited - split second difference. And answer should be provided as an answer not as  a comment,moreover,if you read correctly, I already credited the original author of the comment.

Comment: Now THAT was a proper explanation :) +1